# What is the proper term for the synchronization of eye movements?

Tags: terminology, vision, eye-movement

In humans and most two eyed species, eye movements synchronize so that both eyes are focused on the same point. This facilitates 3D vision significantly, allowing bifocal cues. I remember reading a bit about this but I can't recall the actual term or any related words I would use to find more information on the phenomenon.

What is this "synchronization" called?

Answer (score 5):

**binocular coordination**

Linked below is a general overview of binocular coordination which also describes how, due to independent saccades events, mammalian eyes are generally *not* actually very well "synchronized".

Kirkby JA, Webster LA, Blythe HI, Liversedge SP. (2008) Binocular coordination during reading and non-reading tasks. Psychol Bull. 134(5):742-63

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18729571

Comment: I'm also seeing binocular fusion and convergence coming up; are those basically synonyms or distinct concepts?

Comment: Convergence refers specifically to eyes pointing more toward each other as objects enter nearfield, fusion is when each eye has its own image but a single image is perceived.